# Geolocation doesn't work through the web frame

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, geolocation

I've created a mobile web site, where is my location function works fine on all browsers including Safari on iOS and Android native browser:

```
function getLocation()
  {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  }

function showPosition(position)
  {
position.coords.longitude;
  var ox = position.coords.latitude;
  var oy = position.coords.longitude;
  alert(ox);
```

I'm getting an alert (ox) on safari and Android native browser. After which my task was to display this page in the application through the web frame, and get the same result.

In the iOS app it works perfectly - I'm calling the function and getting an alert with altitude, longitude and everything like on the mobile web site.

But in the Android application nothing happens when I click the button that calls the function.

Can somebody tell me why this doesn't work? Should I use not only Javascript but also some Android code?